# thread synchronisation issue

Tags: c++, multithreading

In the following example i have called the `pthread_join()` for both the threads in the end(before i print the sum). Even though it is expected that the sum should be 0, it prints any value. I know that if i do `pthread_join(id1,NULL)` just before the creation of the 2nd thread then it would work fine(it does), but i don't understand why should not it work when i call join for both threads in the end.

*Because **sum** is printed only after both the threads must have finished execution completely. So, after the execution of the first thread, it must have added 2000000 to the variable sum and second thread must have subtracted 2000000 from the sum sum SHOULD BE 0*

```
long long sum=0;

void* counting_thread(void* arg)
{   
    int offset = *(int*) arg;
    for(int i=0;i<2000000;i++)
    {
        sum=sum+offset;
    }
    pthread_exit(NULL);
}
int main(void)
{
    pthread_t id1;
    int offset1 = 1;
    pthread_create(&id1,NULL,counting_thread,&offset1);

    pthread_t id2;
    int offset2 = -1; 
    pthread_create(&id2,NULL,counting_thread,&offset2);

    pthread_join(id1,NULL);
    pthread_join(id2,NULL);

    cout<<sum;
}
```

Comment: What is this code trying to do anyway?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that the `sum=sum+offset;` is not thread safe.

This is causing some sums not to be counted.

As you specified C++, `std::atomic<long long> sum;`  Would help, but you need to use `+=` operator, rather than the thread-unsafe `sum = sum + count;`

```
sum += offset;
```

A mutex to block updates would also help.

Without these changes, the compiler can produce code, which

- Reads `sum` at the beginning of the function, having only one thread applying its changes.
- Have a stale value of `sum` for the addition.
- Incorrect state from cache.

### read optimization

The compiler can legitimately read the value of sum when the thread starts, add offset to it n times, and store the value.  This would mean only one thread would work.

### stale value

Consider the following *assembly* code.

```
read sum
add offset to sum
store sum

thread1                     thread2
1 read sum                     
2 add offset to sum            read sum
3 store sum                    add offset to sum
4 read sum                     store sum
5 add offset to sum            read sum
6 store sum                    add offset to sum
```

Line 3 of thread 2 adds the offset to the old value which makes line 3 of thread one get lost.

### Incorrect state from cache

In multi-threaded systems, then the cache may be inconsistent between threads of the process.

That would mean that even after `sum+=offset` has been executed, then another core/CPU may see the pre-updated value.

This allows the CPUs to run faster, as they can ignore sharing the data between them.  However, when 2 threads are accessing the same data, this needs to be taken into account.

`std::atomic` / mutex ensures :-

1. The value is modified atomically (as if the `sum = sum + count` is indivisible).
2. The value is visible across the cores/CPUs consistently.
3. The compiler doesn't re-order the load/store of sum as if it couldn't be changed.

Comment: Could you please explain in more detailed way. My question is simple. Question is that , whatever order the statement gets executed , _finally_ the sum should be 0.

Comment: The question is simple, but in no way does this guarantee a simple answer.

Comment: Yes it did. but you have mentioned sum+=offset would work with atomic. why is it so? arent  sum=sum+offset and sum+=offset same?

Comment: @anurag86. They are mathematically the same, but the sum = sum + offset. Has a read, add and store.  There is no atomic operation. sum += offset has a single increment, that has the guarantee.

Answer (score 5):

You can end up with any result without synchronization, because `add` operation is not *atomic*.

### On the basic level

Your

```
sum=sum+offset;
```

is actually

```
fetch sum to register # tmp := sum
add offset            # tmp := tmp + offset
store new value       # sum := tmp
```

Now imagine 2 threads working simultaneously

```
Thread1     Thread2    Sum
tmp:= 1     tmp:=1     1
tmp:= 1+1   tmp:=1-1   1
-zzz-       sum := 0   0
sum := 2     -zzz-     2
```

In this serai of computations result of Thread 2 subtraction is lost

If I change timing a bit

```
Thread1     Thread2    Sum
sum := 2     -zzz-     2
-zzz-       sum := 0   0
```

I will get lost Thread 1 addition

### Add some optimizer

Now things go worse. If you do not synchronize, compiler assumes that no raсe can happen (because compiler always trust in you)

So it will skip fetching and storing part And just transform code to

```
fetch sum to register # tmp := sum
add offset N times    # for (i := 1 ; i < 2000000; i++) tmp := tmp + offset
store result          # sum := tmp
```

or even

```
fetch sum to register # tmp := sum
add offset * N        # tmp := tmp + 2000000 * offset
sore tmp              # sum := tmp
```

Now imagine two threads working simultaneously here

### Add some machine-dependent behaviour

The basic ideas are covered earlier, but not only compiler can be blamed here but your platform itself. Caching mechanism allows faster data access, but if cache is not being synchronized different threads could read different values of the same variable

Answer (score 2):

You have no synchronization between the two threads which are concurrently modifying the global variable sum.  You need a mutex around the code or you need to use one of the platform provided atomic increment/decrement functions.

When you fail to synchronize the threads properly this code suffers from the 'lost update' problem.   See this link about what Oracle terms Thread Interference. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/interfere.html   They're talking about Java but the same holds true for C/C++.  sum = sum + offset is not an atomic operation.   Most platforms have operations to atomically update a variable such as InterlockedIncrement on Windows and _sync_add_and_fetch() on  Linux.

**EDIT**: This very program was also studied in detail in Anthony Williams's article "[Avoiding the Perils of C++0x Data Races](http://www.devx.com/cplus/Article/42725)".

Comment: My question really is that even if i am not using mutex the sum should be zero.

Comment: @anurag86, no it shouldn't be. If your question is _why I could get not zero without any synchronization_ you should ask it explicitly because it is easier to answer than covering all possible solutions to make it working correctly.

Comment: @Lol4t0 : My question is very simple. Please dont over complicate it. I just want to ask why would the sum not be zero _Because sum is printed only after both the threads must have finished execution completely_ . If i run first thread alone then the sum would be 200000, if i run the second thread alone then the sum would be -200000. If i run both the threads and let them finish executing completely then irrespective of whether they are synchronised or not , the sum shold be 0.

Comment: When you fail to synchronize the threads properly this code suffers from the 'lost update' problem.   See this link about what Oracle terms Thread Interference. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/interfere.html   They're talking about Java but the same holds true for C/C++.  sum = sum + offset is not an atomic operation.   Most platforms have operations to atomically update a variable such as InterlockedIncrement on Windows and _sync_add_and_fetch() on  Linux.

Comment: @JJF: thnx JJF. I think this is it. Let me read the whole article

Comment: Happy to help. If this answer or any other one solved your issue, please mark it as accepted.  Thanks